# (Un)boundedness of real-valued homomorphism on some lattice.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-homomorphism

Let $\mathbb{Z}^k$ denote the finitely-generated free abelian group on $k$ generators and consider an *injective* homomorphism $$\chi \colon (\mathbb{Z}^k,+) \to (\mathbb{R},+).$$ Now let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of pairwise *distinct* elements in $\mathbb{Z}^k$. My question is:

> Does there exist a subsequence of $(a_n)$ such that $\vert \chi(a_n) \vert$ tends to $+\infty$?

The answer for $k=1$ is yes as then $\chi$ corresponds to a non-zero multiplication and one can extract a subsequence of $(a_n) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ either going towards $+ \infty$ of $-\infty$.

For $k>1$ this seems more subtle and I'm not sure anymore whether the answer to the question is affermative. Maybe the following bit might be helpful:

Observe that $\chi$ can be viewed as a vector $(\chi_1, \dots, \chi_k) \in \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $$\chi(b^1,\dots b^k)=\langle (\chi_1, \dots,\chi_k),(b^1,\dots,b^k) \rangle=\sum_{i=1}^k \chi_i \cdot b^i.$$ Injectivity of $\chi$ then implies that the $(\chi_i)_{i=1}^k \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Can your figure out how to prove that there exist integer sequences $(p_n), (q_n)$ such that $p_n - q_n\pi \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair yeah, there exists such a sequence as $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$  is dense! Got it, thanks!

Comment: It's a little stronger than just density of $\Bbb Q$. Instead of $\pi$, it would be easier to prove for an irrational number such as $$\sum_n 2^{-2^n}$$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Don't we just need that if $\frac{p_n}{q_n} \to \pi$ (with positive integers $p_n,q_n$), then $p_n$ and $q_n$ tend to $+ \infty$?

Comment: No, because $q_n$ can grow faster than $\frac{p_n}{q_n} - \pi$ shrinks, in which case $p_n - q_n\pi$ would also grow. By carefully choosing the two sequences, you probably can avoid this when using $\pi$. But it is practically obvious that you can avoid it for the other irrational number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally just left a comment since I only had a general concept and didn't have the time to work out the details. But since comments are ephemeral, and I've since put more thought into it, I am giving a proper answer.

Let $$\eta = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-2^k}$$

Since its binary expansion does not repeat, $\eta$ must be irrational. for all $n\ge 0$, let $$q_n = 2^{2^n},\quad p_n = \lfloor q_n\eta \rfloor$$
Then $$0 \le q_n\eta - p_n = 2^{2^n}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 2^{-2^k} < 2^{2^n}\sum_{l=2^{n+1}}^\infty 2^{-l} = 2^{2^n}2^{1-2^{n+1}} = 2^{1-2^n} \to 0$$
as $n \to \infty$.

Therefore the map $\chi : \Bbb Z^2 \to \Bbb R : (n, m) \mapsto n + m\eta$ is an injective homorphism of additive groups, and there exists a sequence $(a_n) = (-p_n) \times (q_n)$ such that $\chi(a_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and therefore the same is true of all subsequences. The pairwise distinct criterion follows from $q_n = 2^{2^n}$.

Comment: very nice, thanks alot!